# Creating nested models on the fly using types.reference in mobx-state-tree

Tags: mobx-state-tree

I have a several models that reference each other. Here is an example.

```
export const AlbumModel = types
  .model("Album")
  .props({
    id: types.identifier,
    name: types.string,
    artists: types.array(ArtistModel),
    uri: types.string,
    releaseDate: types.maybe(types.string),
    images: types.array(types.maybe(ImageModel))
  })

export const ArtistModel = types
  .model("Artist")
  .props({
    id: types.identifier,
    name: types.string,
    uri: types.string
  })

export const ImageModel = types
  .model("Image")
  .props({
    url: types.identifier,
    width: types.maybe(types.number),
    height: types.maybe(types.number)
  })
```

Then, when I go to create an album, I do something like this:

```
Album.create({
  id: '12345',
  name: 'My Cool Album',
  artists: [{
    id: '67890',
    name: 'Mr. Bean',
    uri: 'https://my-cool-site.com/artist/mr-bean'
  }],
  uri: 'https://my-cool-site.com/album/my-cool-album',
  releaseDate: '12-12-2012',
  images: [{
    url: 'https://my-cool-site.com/pic/1'
  }]  
})
```

This works fine, but when I fetch data from a service, I get a bunch of JSON I want to stick into the mst. When I do that as is, I am creating duplicate artists and images.

**Question**
Is there a (simple-ish) way I can create the artists and images on the fly, and pass them as reference to the Album model. Or do I need to write a separate function that will create the images and artists, stick them into the tree, and then reference them as a part of the album?

**What I tried**:

```
export const AlbumModel = types
  .model("Album")
  .props({
    id: types.identifier,
    name: types.string,
    artists: types.array(types.reference(ArtistModel)),
    uri: types.string,
    releaseDate: types.maybe(types.string),
    images: types.array(types.maybe(types.reference(ImageModel)))
  })
```

which throws the following error:

```
at path "/images/0" snapshot `{"height":300,"url":"https://my-cool-site.com/pic/1","width":300}` is not assignable to type: `(reference(Image) | undefined)` (No type is applicable for the union), expected an instance of `(reference(Image) | undefined)` or a snapshot like `(reference(Image) | undefined?)` instead.
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @SaschaGehlich - no. I had to manually write a function that would check if a model with the same id existed, and if it didn't it would create the model and then pass it as reference. I feel like this should be baked into mst

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but it's worth trying

If you put this in AlbumModel artists

```
    types.reference(ArtistModel, {
        // given an identifier, find the user
        get(artist /* string */, parent: any /*AlbumModel*/) {
            return parent.artists.find(a => a.id === artist.id) || ArtistModel.create(data)
        },
        // given a user, produce the identifier that should be stored
        set(artist /* ArtistModel */) {
            return artist.id
        }
    })
```

The idea is initially it tries to find if the artist already exists, if not it will create a new ArtistModel.

Please let me know if this works :)

Comment: When I do this, MST is still complaining that I'm trying to pass a snapshot to a reference type field